# Ca not get Claims information while login Azure active B2B directory

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-b2b

I can not get ClaimsPrincipal after login in azure Ad Web API,
Below is my code added in startup.auth.cs

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope= OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                },

                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },
            });
```

I get Access Token in

```
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientCredential);
```

but can not get ClaimsPrincipal. I get AuthenticationType = null, IsAuthenticated = null, Name = null.

My application use adal.js for UI side to get user information, and get user information successfully.

Comment: You need to configure JWT Bearer token authentication middleware instead of Open Id Connect.

Comment: and you should not use cookie authentication with APIs. Only Bearer.

Comment: Can any one share link how to do with JWT Bearer token validation for Web Api project? I can't get any thing which can work for me.

Comment: I was change startup.auth.cs code by below dcode  app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                },
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]
            }); Then also can't get claimsprinicpal

Comment: I was try for JWT Bearer Token,  it give me to create token and use it, But to create token it require username, and I don't have it, because I use Azure active directory for login.

Answer (score 0):

I got Solution for this problem.replace startup.auth.cs code with

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication( new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions { TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { SaveSigninToken = true, ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"], AuthenticationType = "Bearer" }, Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"], });
```

this code and it working fine